# Trying to use math.net to calculate pseudoinverse of non square matrix

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am trying to use `math.net` library to compute the pseudoinverse of a matrix, but so far  I have gotten an error telling me when I try to use this below code :

```
   B = A.Inverse();
```

that the matrix must be square. However here

http://iridium.mathdotnet.com/api/mathnet.numerics.linearalgebra/matrix.htm#Inverse

it is said that the inverse method calculates the pseudoinverse.
This is also said here:

https://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/discussions/251084

Am I using the wrong version of the library?  So far I have been using `Math.Net.Numerics3.4.0`, I added a reference to a c# project to `MathNetNumerics.dll` found in the folder Net4.0

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/discussions/251084

Comment: Math.Net.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.DenseMatrix does not contain a definition for 'Identity' when using suggestion above

Comment: This could be a good question if you showed the definition of `A`, etc.  Because the exact type could have a significant effect.

Comment: You need to replace DenseMatrix.Identity with DenseMatrix.CreateIdentity, and that's all

Comment: Wouter Huysentruit is right, except DenseMatrix.Identity must be replaced with DenseMatrix.CreateIdentity

Comment: Wouldn't the pseudo inverse be `(A.Transpose()*A).Inverse()*A.Transpose()` or whatever equivalent statements `Math.Net` uses?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](http://nmath.sourceforge.net/doc/numerics/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix.Inverse.html):

> inverse(A) if A is square, pseudoinverse otherwise.

To me this looks like the Matrix.Inverse() method will fail if given a non-invertible (but square) matrix. This behavior may be intentional. Sometimes a non-invertible matrix represents a serious error that you want to be alerted about. Also, if you know that the matrix should always be invertible when square, Inverse MAY be slightly faster than PseudoInverse.